# CMake + Link error + Whitespace in path

Tags: macos, whitespace, cmake, cuda

I'm trying to compile my CUDA project with CMake 2.8.2.
My SDK is located in "/Developed/GPU Computing/" (OSX). The problem is the whitespace in the path, thus CMake doesn't find the libs.

I tried:
link_libraries("-L${CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR}/lib -lcutil")

Result:
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: Computing/C/lib: No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Install CUDA SDK without whitespaces in the path?

Comment: I would also like to distribute my project and I cannot assume that the CUDA SDK is installed in that way on the different machines.

Comment: could you post more of the cmake file?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:target_link_libraries) command

```
target_link_libraries(NameOfProject ${CUDA_SDK_LIBRARIES})
```

Make sure that CUDA_SDK_LIBRARIES points to the full path of the cuda libraries.